# Opening Word Doc with VBA results in empty variable

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy the contents of a Word document into any cell in Excel. I have the filepath and filename of the document.

I get a variable with 'Nothing' as the value for the contents of the Word document (variable name = wdoc).

```vb
Sub readEmails()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim sFileSmall As String, sFileYear As String, sFilePath As String
Dim wapp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' USER INPUT
sFileSmall = "C:\Users\filesToRead\"


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
sFilePath = sFileSmall

' Get variable with filenames from folder (Only contains word docs)
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.getfolder(sFilePath)

i = 1

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value = oFile.Name
    
    Set wapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wapp Is Nothing Then
        Set wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    wapp.Visible = True
    Set wdoc = wapp.Documents.Open(sFilePath & oFile) '<---- Error here. Assigns an empty variable
   ' Range("a1:a1") = wdoc.Content.Text
    
    i = i + 1
    
Next oFile

End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly you're trying to join the filepath-string with the file-object. Try using file name instead: sFilePath & oFile.Name

Comment: A side-note: When you do `...As Word.Whatever`, it implies that you have created a reference to the word library i.e. you are using early binding as opposed to late binding (which btw you are using with the `FileSystemObject` object). To be consistent, you should be using the early-bound `Set wapp = New Word.Application` instead of the late-bound (no reference needed) version (`Set wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application"`). Makes me wonder if there is an early-bound version of `Set wapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")`!?

Comment: @Slaqr i took your comment and it worked.

Comment: @vbasic2008 can you explain late binding versus early binding? I'm a little confused to the difference and why I would need. I also ended up taking out some code to only have ``` set wapp = createobject("word.application") ``` because it was simpler

Comment: @RichardStrott In your code snippet you use late binding for the `FileSystemObject`. This requires a variable to first be declared as a generic object, before using `CreateObject()` to bind the specific object. Early binding often requires certain references to be enabled in the VBA editor; For FileSystemObject this is Microsoft Scripting Runtime) Enabling this reference allows you to use: `Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject`. Early binding is usually better for performance, while late binding can be beneficial when the code is run on a system that lacks one of the libraries referenced.

Comment: @RichardStrott I've submitted my first comment as an answer so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

This error is the result of inputting an incompatible variable type into the *Documents.Open()* method.

```
Set wdoc = wapp.Documents.Open(sFilePath & oFile)
```

The *Documents.Open()* method requires a filename as a string to be input.
While **sFilePath** is declared as a string, **oFile** is declared as an object.

In this case the *.Name* property of the File-object produces the desired string. Thus the correct code is:

```
 Set wdoc = wapp.Documents.Open(sFilePath & oFile.Name)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot